# Vagrant synced folder on Windows D:\ drive

Tags: windows, vagrant, parallels

I am having an issue creating a synced folder on a windows 10 D:\ drive
I have the following in my Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "~/code/", "D:/code/"
```

When I vagrant up I see:

```
dev: D:/code => /Users/myusername/code
```

It looks like it creates the folder on the `D:\` drive but when I look at it's properties, it shows `//psf/D:_code` which <strike>obviously is not correct</strike> creates a share named:

```
Y:        \\psf\D_code              Parallels Shared Folders
```

So it doesn't match up with the shortcut created in the D:\ drive.

Firstly, is what I am trying to do possible? If so what am I doing wrong?

What I am running:

- Vagrant v1.7.4
- vagrant-parallels v1.5.0
- Parallels v10.3.0
- Host OS: OSX ElCapitan
- Guest OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed in the vagrant-parallels provider.
https://github.com/Parallels/vagrant-parallels/pull/221